# File upload stuck on large files with Spring Web on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, nginx, file-upload, jhipster

I have a JHipster application providing a REST endpoint for uploading files.

This code works without any problem in a Docker container on a Linux machine but seems to be stuck in the same Docker container running on Windows.

```java
@PostMapping("/datafiles")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<DataFileDTO> createDataFile(@Valid @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile data,
        @Valid @RequestHeader("workspaceId") Long workspaceId, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
        throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    log.debug("REST request to save a data content");

    DataFileDTO result = dataFileService.createFromData(data, workspaceId);

    return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/datafiles/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString())).body(result);
}
```

This code works for 12Mb video file but when I try to upload a file which is 70Mb, no debug log appears and the server is blocked until I get a timeout from *undertow*

```
    Jan 29 15:26:46 StorageService StorageService-dockerstorage_storageservice-app_1.network:8081: ERROR - io.undertow.request : UT005023: Exception handling request to /api/datafiles
java.io.IOException: UT000128: Remote peer closed connection before all data could be read
    at io.undertow.conduits.FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.exitRead(FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.java:338)
    at io.undertow.conduits.FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.read(FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.java:255)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSourceChannel.read(DetachableStreamSourceChannel.java:209)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$ReadDispatchChannel.read(HttpServerExchange.java:2343)
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels.readBlocking(Channels.java:294)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.readIntoBuffer(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:192)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:168)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.MultiPartParserDefinition$MultiPartUploadHandler.parseBlocking(MultiPartParserDefinition.java:223)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:792)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Changing the timeout just leaves the server waiting but nothing happens on my part of code.

Is there something specific to Windows in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that the problem is not on the JHipster side but is related to the configuration of the NGinx Docker container running the frontend.
It seems that the default configuration is different in this case.